# What do you call a pupil who goes somewhere else in name of going to school?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a pupil who goes somewhere else in name of going to school?

Is there a particular word for it?

Comment: Informal: *playing hookey*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formal word for him would be a [*Truant*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+truant&oq=define+truant)

A truant is a child (boy or girl) who deliberately avoids school.
The child is also said to be *playing truant* while doing this.

There are several slang terms, which tend to vary both from place to place and over time.

Comment: As far as I know a *truant* could just as easily apply to a girl as a boy (the OP mentioned *boy*). I have never heard of a *truantess*.

Comment: @WS2: True, that's why I said *child* in the answer.  I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't think there is a word that specifically targets boys. I'd edit my post to replace "boy" with "pupil". "Truant" is the word I was looking for.